# How to install mongodb database tools in a Dockerfile?

Tags: mongodb, docker

Pretty much the question. Here's what I have currently:

```
FROM node:15 as server
WORKDIR /app
ENV NODE_ENV=production
COPY server/package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY server/ ./
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install -y mongo-tools
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["node", "src/app.js"]
```

Which does work however mongo-tools is a really outdated version of the tools and is not fit for my pusposes.

[Mongo Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/installation/installation-linux/) has instructions for how to install the newer mongodb-database-tools on linux/windows/macos but I can't figure out how to get it to work in a DockerFile.

For anyone wondering, I'm trying to get a node-cron to periodically call mongodump on a mongodb atlas database.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can download newer version of the tools and install it, just like you do on linux host

example Dockerfile like below:

```
FROM node:15 as server
WORKDIR /app
ENV NODE_ENV=production
RUN wget https://fastdl.mongodb.org/tools/db/mongodb-database-tools-debian92-x86_64-100.3.1.deb && \
    apt install ./mongodb-database-tools-*.deb && \
    rm -f mongodb-database-tools-*.deb
COPY server/package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY server/ ./
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["node", "src/app.js"]
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using `node:alpine` this is how I did it:

```
FROM node:18.17.1-alpine3.18

WORKDIR /usr/local/app

RUN apk --no-cache add mongodb-tools

...
```